# How to get single row of values based on value of another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregation

I am attempting to select the values from the `value` column based on the values in the `name` column.

For example:

```
mysql> select name, value from rss_feed_property_value where rss_feed_id = 31;
+-------------+---------------+
| name        | value         |
+-------------+---------------+
| High        | 45            |
| Description | Rain And Snow |
| Low         | 25            |
| Day         | Fri           |
| Date        | 29 Dec 2017   |
+-------------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have almost achieved this with the following query:

```
select

  if (rfpv.name = 'Date', rfpv.value, null) as `Date`,
  if (rfpv.name = 'High', rfpv.value, null) as `High`,
  if (rfpv.name = 'Low', rfpv.value, null) as `Low`,
  if (rfpv.name = 'Description', rfpv.value, null) as `Description`

from rss_feed rf
join rss_feed_definition rfd on rf.rss_feed_definition_id = rfd.id
join rss_feed_property_value rfpv on rfpv.rss_feed_id = rf.id

where rfd.type = 'weather'
and rf.id = 31
order by rf.id;
```

Which produces the following output:

```
+-------------+------+------+---------------+
| Date        | High | Low  | Description   |
+-------------+------+------+---------------+
| NULL        | 45   | NULL | NULL          |
| NULL        | NULL | NULL | Rain And Snow |
| NULL        | NULL | 25   | NULL          |
| NULL        | NULL | NULL | NULL          |
| 29 Dec 2017 | NULL | NULL | NULL          |
+-------------+------+------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I now flatten the above, by ignoring the null values to leave just a single row like the following:

```
+-------------+------+------+---------------+
| Date        | High | Low  | Description   |
+-------------+------+------+---------------+
| 29 Dec 2017 | 45   | 25   | Rain and Snow |
+-------------+------+------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate by the `rf.id` and use conditional aggregation.  I would use `CASE` expressions here as this syntax would be more widely supported across databases than MySQL's `IF`.

```
SELECT
    rf.id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rfpv.name = 'Date'        THEN rfpv.value END) AS Date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rfpv.name = 'High'        THEN rfpv.value END) AS High,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rfpv.name = 'Low'         THEN rfpv.value END) AS Low,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rfpv.name = 'Description' THEN rfpv.value END) AS Description
FROM rss_feed rf
INNER JOIN rss_feed_definition rfd
    ON rf.rss_feed_definition_id = rfd.id
INNER JOIN rss_feed_property_value rfpv
    ON rfpv.rss_feed_id = rf.id
WHERE
   rfd.type = 'weather' AND
   rf.id = 31
GROUP BY
    rf.id
ORDER BY
    rf.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put `MAX()` around everything that you want to fold together *(`MAX()` ignores `NULL` values)*, and `GROUP BY` the id you're trying to fold everything in to...

```
SELECT
  rf.id,
  MAX(if (rfpv.name = 'Date',        rfpv.value, null))  AS `Date`,
  MAX(if (rfpv.name = 'High',        rfpv.value, null))  AS `High`,
  MAX(if (rfpv.name = 'Low',         rfpv.value, null))  AS `Low`,
  MAX(if (rfpv.name = 'Description', rfpv.value, null))  AS `Description`
FROM
  rss_feed                   AS rf
INNER JOIN
  rss_feed_definition        AS rfd
    ON rf.rss_feed_definition_id = rfd.id
INNER JOIN
  rss_feed_property_value    AS rfpv
    ON rfpv.rss_feed_id = rf.id
WHERE
      rfd.type = 'weather'
  AND rf.id = 31
GROUP BY
  rf.id
ORDER BY
  rf.id
;
```

I added the field `rf.id` to the `SELECT` just to make it a little more clear what is being done.  *(And so also added the associated `GROUP BY rf.id`)*

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this with the following query:

```
select

  rf.id as rssFeedId,

  (select value
   from rss_feed_property_value
   where name = 'Date'
   and rss_feed_id = rssFeedId) as `Date`,

   (select value
   from rss_feed_property_value
   where name = 'High'
   and rss_feed_id = rssFeedId) as `High`,

   (select value
   from rss_feed_property_value
   where name = 'Low'
   and rss_feed_id = rssFeedId) as `Low`,

   (select value
   from rss_feed_property_value
   where name = 'Description'
   and rss_feed_id = rssFeedId) as `Description`


from rss_feed rf
join rss_feed_definition rfd on rf.rss_feed_definition_id = rfd.id
join rss_feed_property_value rfpv on rfpv.rss_feed_id = rf.id

where rfd.type = 'weather'
and rf.id = 31

group by rf.id

order by rf.id;
```

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing it though.

Comment: If you do go such a route, you don't need the last `JOIN` on to `rfpv` as your correlated sub-queries are doing that for you, which in turn means that you won't need the `GROUP BY`.  That said, a single `JOIN` and a `GROUP BY` will be much faster than 4 correlated sub-queries.